# How to save the content from a wysisyg inline-editor to a .php file

Tags: javascript, php, html, editor, inline

I found a '[HTML5 WYSISYG Inline Editor](http://www.barneyparker.com/world-simplest-html5-wysisyg-inline-editor/)', I have it working on my localhost(Ubuntu 14.04).

The purpose for this is, to embed it in my website, and use it as my main writing tool for my website. I need to be able to choose the filename or have it add `-` in the whitespace of the filename.

this is the code i wrote on it to save its content

([CodePen from original author: HTML5 WYSISYG Inline Editor](http://codepen.io/barney-parker/pen/idjCG))

inline.php

```
  <form action="effe.php" method="post">

      <input type="text" name="author" value="" placeholder="Author">
      <input type="text" name="header" value="" placeholder="header">
      <input type="datetime" name="datetime" value="" placeholder="datetime">

    <div id='editor' contenteditable contextmenu="mymenu" name='editor'>
      <p>This is just some example text to start us off</p>
    </div>


    <div class="tags">

      <input type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="tag">
      <input type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="tag">
      <input type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="tag">

    </div>


    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

save.php

```
<?php

if (!empty($_POST))
{
    foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value )
    {
        if ( ( !is_string($value) && !is_numeric($value) ) || !is_string($key) )
            continue;

?>

        <?php echo htmlspecialchars( (string)$key ); ?>

<div class="article-meta">
   <a class="author" rel="author" title="author" href="/about" target="_blank"><?php echo "$author";?></a> 

   <time datetime="<?php echo "$datetime";?>" title="<?php echo "$datetime";?>"><?php echo "$datetime";?></time>

</div> 

<h1><?php echo "$header"; ?></h1>

<?php echo "$editor"; ?>

    <div class="tags">

      <span> <?php echo "$tag1"; ?> </span>
      <span> <?php echo "$tag2"; ?> </span>
      <span> <?php echo "$tag3"; ?> </span>

    </div>

    <?php
    }
}
?>
```

RESULT:

[image: result]

I have been at this for a good day, and am just not seeing what am doing wrong. Do note that my `php` knowledge is pretty basic.

I know using a `db` is an option, but at the top of my head, i only wrote like `20+` article in the past year or two. When i hit a 100 articles i will consider switching to a database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what it is you;re trying to accomplish.  I was the author of the article you mentioned, and I'd be glad to help.

I'm not sure the method you;re trying to use is practical.  The best option here would be to set up a database and write the content in there.

With php thats pretty easy, I would suggest taking a look at PDO, the database abstraction layer.  There are some others, but this one does some work for you relating to injection attacks etc so it's a nice starting point.

It sounds like you need a fairly simple database table, most likely something like:

```
create table articles (
  article_id INT NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT,
  title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  content TEXT NOT NULL,
  article_date DATE
  PRIMARY KEY (tutorial_id)
);
```

When you POST data back from your editor form, you can do something like:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=articles', 'user', 'pwd');
$sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO articles (title, content, article_date) values (:title, :content, NOW())');
$sth->bindParam(':title', $_POST['title']);
$sth->bindParam(':content', $_POST['content']);
$sth->execute();
```

To recall that back out of the database, use something like:
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=articles', 'user', 'pwd');
    $sth = $dbh->query('SELECT * FROM articles');

There's a little more to it than this, for example you'll want to add a try/catch block to avoid errors, and you may want to select a specific article (i.e. SELECT * FROM articles where article_id=45) but this I hope will point you in the right direction.

I think trying to avoid using a database will cause a lot of extra work, and once you start using something like MySQL you'll be up and running in no time!

Comment: So save the content of the `<div id='editor'...`, to a `x.php` file. Thanks for the link to mozilla doc! looks really helpfull!

Comment: @blade19899 sorry, I re-read the question and updated my answer as I felt my original answer was not correct at all.  Hopefully the answer i've added is more complete and more helpful to you.  Feel free to get in touch directly if you want a bit more help :)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply(work, exams, women.) I don't have that many articles, so for now - as is stated in my A - i want to save the content from the editor, in a `.php`. i will look in to databases in the future.

Comment: it can be done, but it's not great practice to give your web server the ability to write to the web root....  Potentially an attacker could compromise the server by writing malicious files there...

Comment: It's just for educational purposes! besides i don't have a high profile website.